# Django - select model linked to itself

Tags: python, django

Jello!

I'm working with django right now and I have a problem which I suspect has a simple solution, but I've had a lot of difficulty trying to find it (most of the relevant keywords tend to point google to the wrong places).

I'm looking to filter a query based on the criteria that: **A model has a field that points to itself**.

I'll give an example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('app.Person', null=True)

gramps = Person.objects.create(name='Tod', parent=None)
pops = Person.objects.create(name='Hank', parent=gramps)
sonny_boy = Person.objects.create(name='Tim', parent=pops)

temporal_paradox_dude = Person.objects.create(name='Emmett')
temporal_paradox_dude.parent = temporal_paradox_dude
temporal_paradox_dude.save()

temporal_paradox_dude_2 = Person.objects.create(name='Arnold')
temporal_paradox_dude_2.parent = temporal_paradox_dude_2
temporal_paradox_dude_2.save()
```

So the question is, in this case, how can I query the `Person` table for only people who are temporally paradoxical?

```
>>> Person.objects.filter(parent=SOME_WAY_OF_DECLARING_ITSELF)
[ 'Emmett', 'Arnold' ]
```

What do I need to replace `SOME_WAY_OF_DECLARING_ITSELF` with in order to get models that link to themselves?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you looking for something like this;

```
from django.db.models import F

Person.objects.filter(parent_id=F('id'))
```

Comment: I believe this is very much what I'm looking for! Would you mind quickly explaining why it's `parent_id` instead of `parent` in your example? To me it looks like it should at least be `parent__id`.

Comment: parent_id is the direct column name in table.

Answer (score -1):

You could do a simple query and then filter by iterating through that query:

```
results = [x for x in Person.objects.all() if x.parent == x]
```

Comment: This will work, but will query the entire table (if there are millions of `Person` records in the table this would be unacceptable)